# OpenGL refuses to draw a triangle

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm attempting to draw a single large triangle in a window in OpenGL. My program compiles and runs, but I get just a black screen in my window.

I've checked and double-checked multiple tutorials and it seems like my steps are correct... Am I missing something obvious?

Here is the program in its entirety:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

GLuint VBO;

struct vector {
  float _x;
  float _y;
  float _z;
  vector() { }
  vector(float x, float y, float z) { _x = x; _y = y; _z = z; }
};

void render()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void create_vbo()
{
  vector verts[3];
  verts[0] = vector(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
  verts[1] = vector(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
  verts[2] = vector(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    glewInit();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    create_vbo();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** It turns out that drawing this way without a "program" (that is, compiled shader files) produces undefined behavior (the newer your graphics card, the more likely it is to work, however).

Because my card is right on the edge and only supports OpenGL 2.1, it was a little difficult to find an appropriate shader example that would work -- seems like there are many different tutorials out there written at different stages in the evolution of OpenGL.

My vertex shader (entire file):

```
void main()
{
  gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

My fragment shader (entire file):

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4,0.4,0.8,1.0);
}
```

I used the example `LoadShaders` function from [this OpenGL Tutorial Site](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) to create the program, and now, I, too, can see the triangle!

(Thanks to @chbaker0 for pointing me in the right direction.)

Comment: It draws a triangle for me. Can you try replacing your `vector` array with just an array of floats and uploading that to your buffer? Technically C++ doesn't guarantee how those structs will be laid out.

Comment: Didn't realize that!  I tried just uploading an array of float[9] instead, and still no triangle.  The fact that the code _works_ for you is useful info though... Could it be OpenGL version?  I printed `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` from within my program and got `2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.43 310.41.05f0`.  I'm not doing anything outside of OpenGL 2.0, am I?

Comment: I have an OpenGL 4.4 compatibility context, so it's very much within the realm of possibilities. I'm looking at some docs now to see.

Comment: Something does come to mind though: you're using programmable pipeline features without using shaders, so it might just be OpenGL undefined behavior we're experiencing. Since I have an AMD card while you have NVidia, they just might be responding differently to it. However I'm not sure; I've only personally worked with OpenGL 3.3+ core contexts.

Comment: @chbaker0, it was shaders after all.  Feel free to post in answer form if you'd like.  I will update the question with my exact steps as well.

Comment: @ElliotNelson, you should post your Update as an answer.

Comment: @ElliotNelson: the code does _not_ produce undefined behavior, and drawing without shaders is fine in GL 2.x. Furthermore, your shader using `ftransform()` relies on the aliasing of generic attribute 0 to the builtin vertex attribute in the same way the fixed-function pipeline did. You might just have triggered some driver bug, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I ran into was using pipeline features without defining a shader program. The spec says this *should* work, but on my graphics card it did not did. (See my update in the question for more specifics).

Thanks to all the commenters for nudging me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this will help you or not but in your create_vbo() function where you have:

```
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

try this instead:

```
  glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( verts[0] * 3 ), &verts[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

And after this function call add in this function call to the end of your create_vbo() function

```
// This MUST BE LAST! Used to Stop The Buffer!
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

It is hard for me to see your error. In my projects I do have some vbos, but I am also using vaos as well. My code is able to working in OpenGL 2.0 - 4.5 but for the older versions there is a split in logic because of the deprecated functions within the API. I also do not use glut. I hope this helps.

The other thing I noticed too is did you pay attention to your vertex winding order? Meaning are they being used by OpenGL in a CCW order or  CW order? Is back face culling turned on or off? There are a lot of elements to consider when setting up and configuring an OpenGL context. It has been a while since I worked with older versions of OpenGL but I do know that once you start working with a specific version or newer you will have to supply your own model view projection matrix, just something to consider.